# actions/reducers are not causing a rerender as expected

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, react-redux

I am building a web client (react,redux) & API (mongo, express, node) that will show a list of deals to a user and allow them to "favorite/like" them. I am new to react/redux, as you will be able to tell. I am using axios to make my requests and have successfully rendered a list of deals.  I have a "favorite" button that successfully makes the post request, and the request just sends back the deal that was favorited.. However, the "number of likes" is not updating and does not show the increased number until I manually refresh the page.

Here is my component that successfully produces a list of deals (2)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchDeals, favoriteDeal } from '../actions';

import DealCard from './DealCard';

class DealList extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
      this.props.fetchDeals();
      this.favoriteDeal = this.favoriteDeal.bind(this);
  }

  favoriteDeal = (dealId) => {
    this.props.favoriteDeal(dealId)
  }

  renderDeals(){
    return this.props.deals.map(deal => {
      return(
        <DealCard
          onFavorite = {this.favoriteDeal}
          key={deal._id} 
          {...deal}
        />
      )
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
     <div>
      {this.renderDeals()}
     </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return { 
    deals: state.deals,
    favoriteDeal: state.favoritedDeal
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchDeals, favoriteDeal})(DealList)
```

Below is my individual deal card:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DealCard extends Component {
render() {
    return (
      <div  key={this.props._id} className="card" style={{width: "18rem", marginTop: 10}}>
          <img className="card-img-top" src={this.props.dealImage} style={{maxHeight: 200}} alt="${this.props.dealHeadline}" />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h4>{this.props.dealHeadline}</h4>
            <p className="card-text">{this.props.dealDescription}</p>
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.onFavorite(this.props._id)}>Favorite</button>
              <span>{this.props.dealId}</span>
              <i className="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <p className="card-text">#of Likes: {this.props.dealNumberOfLikes}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DealCard;
```

Below are my action creators:

```
export const fetchDeals = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get('/api/deals')
  dispatch({type: FETCH_DEALS, payload: res.data})
};


export const favoriteDeal = (dealId) => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.post(`/api/deals/${dealId}/favorites`)
  dispatch({type: FAVORITE_DEAL, payload:  res.data})
};
```

and finally my reducers:
// deals reducer

```
import { FETCH_DEALS } from '../actions/types';
export default function (state = [], action){
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_DEALS:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

// favorite deals Reducer
import { FAVORITE_DEAL } from '../actions/types';

export default function (state = {}, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case FAVORITE_DEAL:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

To summarize: I have a list of deals, and each deal has a button that when clicked, "favorites" a deal via an HTTP post request and increases the NumberOfDealLikes by 1.  When the button is clicked, the request is successfully executed and the database shows that the NumberOfDealLikes is increased by one.  However, on the screen, the update is not shown until I manually rerender. As twitter works, I would like to show that the increase happens simultaneously.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: you have not connected your DealCard component to redux store. Hence it does not know that store has been updated and the component has to re-render

Comment: Sujit, thank you for your feedback.  I was just able to solve the problem with Pierre's answer below.  I am trying to limit the amount of containers in my project, which is why I did not hook it up to the connect function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problems lies in your favorite_deal reducer. As you said, the post request sends back the updated deal. It should then replace the old one in the deals array. Your deals reducer should look like:

```
import { FETCH_DEALS, FAVORITE_DEAL } from '../actions/types';
export default function (state = [], action){
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_DEALS:
            return action.payload;
        case FAVORITE_DEAL:
            return state.map((d) => d._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : d);
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

As the deals array is updated, your component will be re-rendered. And you do not need another reducer.

By the way, as you defined the `favoriteDeal` function as a class property with an arrow function, you do not need to bind it to `this`.